# Submit not triggering properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit, postback, colorbox

So I have this form, if I submit it without opening a colorbox popup through `ajax`, it works properly, but if I call the colorbox, the event submit is called but it doesn't send the data to the server (post-back).

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I call the colorbox like this:

```
$(".costumer_choose").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.colorbox({ href : "potatoes", innerWidth : "830px", height : "80%" });
});
```

And this is the submit event:

```
$('form#payment_main').submit(function(){
    console.log('submit');

    $('#chooser input[type=radio]').each(function(){ 
        if ( !$(this).prop('checked') ) {
            $('#' + $(this).data('id')).remove();
        }
    });

    $('#recurring_chooser input[type=radio]').each(function(){ 
        if ( !$(this).prop('checked') ) {
            $('.' + $(this).val()).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

PS: the loaded content is not overwriting any existing var, and `jQuery` is only loaded once.

EDIT 2:
The code inside the submit event is executed but after that, the page doesn't "refresh".

Comment: please post the code, so we can see what is happening

Comment: Look at your handler fired event, it's clear you are misusing it, isn't it?

Comment: Make sure your content which are loading inside colorbox popup do not overwrite any code or global variable or include jQuery twice...